# Getting a list of workspaces on a specific machine with p4

Tags: perforce

I was going to ask this on superuser.com but there were only 5 perforce tags so I came here...
How can I get a list of workspaces on a specific machine with p4?

I can run p4 workspaces, but that gives me all of them, ever. 
How can I filter it down to a specific machine(client) name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends on your environment.  I've included a basic Windows batch file for doing this.

Run `p4 clients`.  Pull the second word out of each line, that's the client name.  Run `p4 client -o <name>`.  Grep for `^Host:.*\b<hostname>\b`.  If grep returns success, that client is for that machine.  Accumulate the list.

In Windows:

```
set CLIENTS=

for /f "tokens=2" %%c in ('p4 clients') do call :ProcessClient %%c

echo clients on %HOSTNAME% are %CLIENTS%
pause
goto :eof

:ProcessClient
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%h in ('p4 client -o %1') do if "Host:%HOSTNAME%"=="%%h%%i" set CLIENTS=%CLIENTS% %1
    goto :eof
```

Comment: In your second paragraph, do you mean "Run `p4 client -o <name>`", not `workspaces` again? That's what you've got in the batch script.

Comment: Ah yes, I fell into P4V terminology between writing the batch file and writing this post about it.  'client' and 'workspace' are interchangeable, although yeah in the second case it shouldn't be plural.  Will fix.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang I understand this is over 10 years old, and today there is no p4sql, but our perforce server is approaching 30k clients, and the obvious loop over all clients approach is incredibly inefficient and slow. Almost makes me wonder if I should dump all client info into some DB, then updating it periodically for client definitions that changed.

Answer (score 4):

I know you specified using P4, but you could also look at P4Report, which gives you SQL query access to Perforce. Once installed, you would just need a query something like:

```
SELECT clients.client FROM clients WHERE (clients.host='enter your machine here')
```

which you can also do from the command line (p4sql -s "query string") So if you don't mind substituting P4SQL for P4 in  you can me more concise than the script suggested.

P4Report can be found in the Tools & Utilities section of the Perforce Downloads page.