# Getting workspace of a specific folder on a specific machine in Perforce

Tags: list, perforce, workspace

I'm writing a script to find all folders on a machine, which not connected to any workspace,
How can I get the workspace name (or null) of a specific folder on a specific host?

(I already examined the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838474/getting-a-list-of-workspaces-on-a-specific-machine-with-p4), but that doesn't answer my question)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use 'p4 where'. Running 'p4 -c  where ' should tell you how Perforce is interpreting the foldername in question for that particular workspace.

If you want to do the detailed analysis yourself:

The root directory of the workspace on the host is stored in the Root: field of the workspace spec and can be displayed with 'client -o'.

Note that there can be AltRoots, that is, multiple valid root directories for a single workspace.

So as you iterate through the workspaces for a specific host, look at their Root and AltRoot directories, and see if any of those directories are the parent of the folder you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your response, what should I get from that command "p4 -c where"? (I'm getting a list of P4 commands)